# What does "fail to clear the legislature" mean?

Tags: meaning

It runs in the text I'm translating in this way: "She encountered fierce opposition (...) and her bill twice failed to clear the legislature."

Comment: Personally, I find this attitude pedantic... I do not want to use "commonly-available references" since they give us limited sense of expressions, and I just want to be sure about the meaning of the expression in question in terms of "living English." After all, this should be a free network. Anyone can be looking for any information concerning English language... Please do not waste your time by labeling people's needs off-topic. Contribute to solidarity of people coming together to pick up the tiniest bit of information anywhere they want. I think this is the right place to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"clear the X" in this case probably comes from expressions like "clear the fence", i.e. "jump clear of the fence", i.e. successfully jump over a physical obstacle without hitting it.

Here it is metaphorical, for a bill to "clear the legislature" would mean for it to successfully overcome the obstacle of being voted on by the legislature and thus enacted.

So here the quote is saying that her bill was twice put to the legislature, and twice failed to be voted on or enacted or whatever steps there exist in the legislature to approve a bill between "be given to the legislature" and "be passed on by the legislature to the next step of the approval process".